# Can Photoshop generate image sequences between the first and last image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

In Photoshop, is there a way to create an image, manipulate it, and then have Photoshop automatically generate several images leading into this manipulation like an animated image sequence?

Let me put it another way if that doesn't make sense. I'm trying to create an animation of a book opening/closing. I could duplicate the image about 10 times and manipulate each one slightly until I get my whole sequence, but is there a faster/easier way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What you're looking for is some [tweening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbetweening).

If you're creating a frame animation in Photoshop you can tween **position**, **opacity**, or **effect parameters**. Nothing more. All you need to do is:

1. Select the frame or frames you want to tween (selecting one frame gives you the option of tweening with the previous or next frame).
2. Hit the Tween button in the Timeline panel or select *Tween...* from the Timeline panel dropdown menu.
3. Select how many frames to add, which layers to tween and which properties to tween from the Tween dialog.
4. Hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.

You can read more about creating frame animations and tweening in Photoshop here:

- [**Photoshop Help / Create frames using tweening**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-frame-animations.html#create_frames_using_tweening)

If you're looking for something more (it sounds like you probably are), you're out of luck with Photoshop. You're better off looking at actual animation software like Adobe Flash/Animate or After Effects (or something else like [Toonboom](https://www.toonboom.com/) or countless other animation software that I've never used).